# Торговый бот Steam на Python

Tags: python, бот, поиск-библиотек, steam

Какие существуют библиотеки для взаимодействия с торговой площадкой Steam для Python?
Какую из них стоит выбрать?
Знаю что большинство подобных ботов написаны на node.js, хотелось бы узнать возможно ли это сделать используя только python

Comment: Обратите внимание на [результаты поиска](https://pypi.org/search/?q=steam) в PyPi.org и посмотрите, есть ли какая из библиотек, которая вас устраивает.

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека *requests*. Методы `requests.Session()`, `requests.post()` вам точно пригодятся. Использование requests принесет гораздо больший опыт в https запросах.

Comment: Первая библиотека в списке [в результатах поиска на pypi](https://pypi.org/search/?q=steam) обновлена 6 февраля 2021 года, и я предполагаю что она рабочая. Так что "часто они старые и нерабочие" в данном случае не аргумент.

Comment: Библиотека requests более гибкая для https/http запросов

Comment: Если есть готовое рабочее решение, нет смысла изобретать свой велосипед на requests.

Comment: Для каждого индивидуально, но если не изобретать велосипед, нужно каждый модуль подобный steam_market проверять на работоспособность

Comment: Смотрите, есть готовое решение, на реализацию и отладку которого автор потратил, допустим 1000 часов. Вы пишете свое как-то работающее решение, и тратите еще 100 часов. Это тупо нерационально. Опыт, конечно, будет получен, но в целом, если основная задача состоит не в написании очередного модуля для работы со steam, а в решении конкретной задачи (торгового бота), то лучше все-таки взять готовое решение, а свое время потратить на что-то более полезное. Я когда-то так писал дизассемблер на Python, убил на него кучу времени, и в итоге его пришлось выкинуть и взять готовый рабочий движок.

Comment: Но таки да, опыт был получен. Если говорить о тех же requests - я писал когда-то библиотеку для vk api, это дало мне какой-то опыт, но одного раза для опыта достаточно, и теперь если нужно работать с каким-то популярным api, я уже в первую очередь ищу готовое решение.

Comment: Вообщем, если автор не светит навыками работы с http запросами, пусть ищет готовое решение. Если шарит в requests или urllib3 пусть сам пишет.